# python code automatically open raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, startup

i have raspberry pi3 raspbian(os)i have some kind of python code (it is related pi camera) i want to start automatically when raspberry pi start is it possible ?

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: Generic way of getting  files to run on startup:  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/8734/execute-script-on-start-up

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autostart OpenVPN on Raspberry Pi (Jessie)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37918959/autostart-openvpn-on-raspberry-pi-jessie)

Answer (score 0):

You can put `#!/bin/env python` on top of your file, then make it executable with `chmod +x <filename>` and then call it from `/etc/rc.local`. rc.local is run whenever that system boots.

Comment: 1 and 2nd step is okey. How can i call it from /etc/rc.local. rc.local is run whenever that system boots.